# error: redefinition of 'int main()' even if "int main()" apperas only once

Tags: c++

I was working on a problem on Pbinfo: https://www.pbinfo.ro/probleme/898/sumfactcif but each time I tried to run my code it said:

```
sumfactcif.cpp: In function 'int main()':
sumfactcif.cpp:35:5: error: redefinition of 'int main()'
 int main(){

     ^
sumfactcif.cpp:25:5: error: 'int main()' previously defined here
 int main()

     ^
```

I don't know what to do because in my IDE(Codebloks) the code has no errors.
Here's the code if you can help me:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int sumfactcif(int x)
{
   int p,p1=0;
   while(x>0)
   {
       int u=x%10;
       p=1;
       for(int i=1;i<=u;i++)
       {
           p=p*i;
       }
       p1=p1+p;
       x=x/10;
   }
   return p1;
}

int main()
{
    int x,fct;
    cin>>x;
    fct=sumfactcif(x);
    cout<<fct;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look at your error message `sumfactcif.cpp:35:5:`. This means the error occurs on line 35. But the code you have posted does not have 35 lines. So whatever the problem is, it's not in the code you have posted here.

Comment: I don't know Romanian, but the problem statement doesn't appear to say anything about taking input and giving output.

Comment: @john, It works locally for the poster. Presumably the site adds code to submissions before compiling them. (Weirdly, indentation appears to be part of that given the column numbers in the error.)

Comment: @chris Like a main function? That makes sense.

Comment: john I know that and that's a question that I have too. I taught that maybe the first number is the character from the line but that has no sense too:(

Comment: @TudorTeo Well it seems that chris has the answer. That web site adds a main function to your code, so you are not supposed to write one yourself (except for your own testing).

Comment: It's just google translate, but I think the warning  is pretty clear. You are not supposed to write a `main` or take any input: _"Important
The proposed solution will only contain the definition of the required function. The presence in the solution of other instructions can lead to compilation or execution errors that will have the effect of de-punctuating the solution."_

Comment: ok I'l try but thanks:D

Comment: yes you're right I missunderstood that sentence

Comment: Yeah, your code is being embedded in an existing scaffolding with its own `main`, so you must not write your own. Because you can't see the scaffolding, it's not obvious, but you just need to follow those instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Looks like the site already added an "int main" to my code, so that the result had two "int mains". Thanks to @churill for pointing that out